# Boost cross compiling for arm, toolset not recognized despite definition in user-config.jam

Tags: linux, boost, arm, cross-compiling

I am try to cross-compile boost 1.52.0 for a freescale ARM processor board from a PC running Linux.

Based on the (rather minimal) documentation on [cross compiling boost](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html), I have set up with a user-config.jam file that reads as follows:

```
using gcc : arm : /mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/cross_compiler/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++ ;
```

I then ran

```
bootstrap.sh --prefix=`realpath ../tools`
./b2 toolset=gcc-arm
```

The results were:

```
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/tools/build/v2/tools/gcc.jam:107: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: version 'arm' requested but 'g++-arm' not found and version '4.3.2' of default 'g++' does not match
error: initialized from
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/tools/build/v2/build/toolset.jam:39: in toolset.using from module toolset
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:481: in process-explicit-toolset-requests from module build-system
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:562: in load from module build-system
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
/mnt/lv1/src/ROM1210/extras/boost_1_52_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

Running b2 with `--debug-configuration` offers little extra info, other than confirming that the correct user-config.jam file is being read.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't my user-config.jam file being loaded, but one packaged with the boost distribution and with a very similar filename.  Always pays to double check these things when something goes wrong!

Comment: I had the same issue... I fixed it by moving the user-config.jam file into my home directory, ~/

Comment: In my case, I have user-config.jam but it still fails to load it. Any ideas?

Comment: So in other words, the documentation lies, and Boost build will NOT in fact check for user-config.jam in the build directory (even though it did in previous versions). Just one more way in which they created the absolute worst build system ever.